# Looking to add CSS class to child if a parent has specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two event types on my page and I wanted to automatically add a CSS class to the `<span>` items in the parent class (div) of the event if their `data-colr="value"`.

For instance:

if `data-colr="#123456"` of the class `.eventon_list_event` exists, add `color="#e1e1e1"` to the `<span>` inside that parent class `.eventon_list_event`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try something..?

Comment: please reconsider giving my answer the best answer check ;0 You should do it like i said, and not like makshh did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="eventon_list_event" data-color="#123456">
  Div
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.span-color {
  color: #f06;
}
```

jQuery:

```
if($('.eventon_list_event').data('color') === '#123456') {
  $('.eventon_list_event').find('span').addClass('span-color');
}
```

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQdeEM)

Comment: bingo! That works like a charm my friend. Much much appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelG But this code is not good... Look at my answer: Each - function that loops through all the instances of the DOM element
If you were to miss that, jquery would take data from the first div instead of all separately. So if you had first `.eventon_list_event` div with a data-colr attribute, and 2 `.eventon_list_event` without this attribute, the colored would be all divs, and not only the first one. Please reconsider trying my answer again

Comment: He did not ask for that. Similarly I could say your answer i wrong because he asks for adding CSS class instead of setting css value. Chill out :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$('.eventon_list_event').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('data-colr') == '#123456') {
        $('this').find('span').css('color', '#e1e1e1');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(){
    if ($(".eventon_list_event").data("colr")=="#123456")
    {
        $(".eventon_list_event span").css("color", "#e1e1e1");
    }
}
```

For multiple **div**s:

```
$(document).ready(){
    $('.eventon_list_event').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data("colr") == '#123456') {
            $(this).find('span').css('color', '#e1e1e1');
        }
    });
}
```

#### Each

- loops through all the instances of the **DOM** element

If you were to miss that, jquery would take data from the first div instead of all separately

Be sure to always write `this` instead of `'this'`

This is the bad way to do it:

[Bad Way](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaoOLK)

And this is the good way:

[Good way](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaoOLK)